# How to Convert Data structure to convert char* in c++

Tags: c++, networking

I'm think pointer is 4Byte or(2Byte) heap memory allocated

I need Structure data convert to char* Just need 12byte convert

this is my code

please Contact me.

thank you

```
   struct MyData {
        unsigned int myNumber;
        float x;
        float y;
    };


int main(){
  Mydata* mydata = new Mydata();
  mydata->userNumber = 188242268;
  mydata->x = 100.0f;
  mydata->y = 102.0f;

  char* sender = (char*)&mydata;



   sioclient->send(sender);
   // SocketIO Server Send
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying. Are you trying to get a pointer to your data? Look into reinterpret_cast

Comment: hmm  want to send a struct  Data to my server. My data is 12 bytes, only 4 bytes are sent. This is the problem.

Comment: yes i try memcpy,  reinterpret_cast. and failed..

Comment: Parameters of `->send`?

Comment: this send() method  in the cocos2d-x SocketIO

Comment: send(const char* msg)

Comment: Oh sorry  send(const std::string& msg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you are asking is possible. `string` doesn't like having `null` characters in itself, which would be necessary to directly send the data (For example, a `int(1)` would have 1 NULL (0x0) character (modern systems would have 3 NULL characters) and 1 0x1 character, which `string` wouldn't like the `null` and terminate the string there).

I think you should find another networking library for what you are doing if you can't use `WebSocket` and need to have the efficiency of sending the bytes of a struct. (Boost::asio perhaps?)

But if you HAVE to use Cocos2d-x SIOClient without the WebSocket, then in the sending side, create a string with the values separated by commas:

```
string sendMe = to_string(mydata->userNumber) + "," + to_string(mydata->x) + "," + to_string(mydata->y);
```

And then on the receiving side:

```
Mydata receiver;
string recStr;//Received string
string temp;
int stage = 0;
for (int itr = 0; itr < temp.length(); itr++)
{
    if (recStr[itr] == ',')
    {
        if (stage==0)
           receiver.myNumber = stoi(temp);
        else if (stage==1)
           receiver.x = stof(temp);

        stage++;
        temp = "";
    }
    else
        temp += recStr[itr];

}
receiver.y = stof(temp);
```

Hope that helps.

**The old answer, in case you want to switch and have a solution:**

Ok, try using the overloaded function

```
void send (const unsigned char * binaryMsg, unsigned int len);
```

instead. [read about it here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.10/d0/dab/classcocos2d_1_1network_1_1_web_socket.html#a5094711b8acd973c0d29ff3268a3b556)

This should look something like the following:

```
sioclient->send(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(mydata), sizeof(MyData));
```

Tell me if you are using a different version of Cocos2d-x and thus this doesn't work, or if it failed to solve the problem. When I tried this, it compiled nicely and seemed to behave correctly.

If your compiler doesn't like `unsigned char*` for a `const unsigned char*` parameter, just add a `const_cast`.

Also, remember to `delete (mydata);` when you are done with it.

Comment: @koboso see if that solves your problem. I highly recommend you switch to something like boost::asio.

Comment: @koboso if that solved your problem, hit the checkmark to the left of the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow :).